# How to set dynamic class name from json data?

Tags: css, class, vue.js, bind

I want to set css class name dynamically for example:

```html
{ "id": "00053", "cssLevel": "53", "username": "user53", "Title": "title53"}
{ "id": "00054", "cssLevel": "54", "username": "user54", "Title": "title54"}

and then

<div class="{{cssLevel}}">{{model.username}}</div>

or

<div v-bind:class="cssLevel">{{model.username}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'd expect your data to be in **model**

```
<div v-bind:class="model.cssLevel">{{model.username}}</div>
```

or

```
<div :class="model.cssLevel">{{model.username}}</div>
```

Should both work for you. You forgot to access the model here (same for the cssLevel as for the username)